# App Engine for Go app update not reflecting

Tags: google-app-engine, go

**Using Google App Engine for Go.**

I have successfully deployed my project update, but it is not reflected back on the Web URL. Does anyone have any idea about that?

I have tried Updating it twice.

Command tried 
     **goapp deploy**
     **appcfg.py update myapp/**

Comment: Is the version number the same or different from the current version?

Comment: The version number is different.

Comment: In that case, I've added an answer for you. On an unrelated side note, there is a newer version of the Google Cloud SDK (which uses "gcloud" instead of "appcfg.py" and Git push-to-deploy), it's probably worth updating your tools to the new Google Cloud SDK.

Comment: I'll try that and will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch version numbers, App Engine will continue serving the old version until you have changed the default version in the App Engine console. This is by design; it allows you to have a newer version running in production that you can test without disrupting existing users (you can also run an A/B test on the different versions that are currently pushed to production).

Comment: I haven't found any default version of App on Google console.

Comment: Visit https://console.developers.google.com, then click on your project, then click on "Versions" under "App Engine" on the left. You should see the list of versions as well as a "Make default" button that lets you check a specific version and make it the default.